# In python, how to extract the (minimal) list of different values in a random sequence with repetitions?

Tags: python, extract, repeat

In **python**, I have a scipy array (can also be just a list), which is a long **random sequence** of floats, but the **possible values** are just 4.
I don't know which are those 4 values, and I need to find them.
What would be the most efficient / **elegant** way to do that?

I have few ideas (sort the list, take the minimum, pop all the subsequent elements equal to that, take the first non-equal, etc.).
Can you come up with something nicer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin `set` function:

```
>>> ar = scipy.array([0.4,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.4,0.4])
>>> set(ar)
set([0.90000000000000002, 0.29999999999999999, 0.20000000000000001, 0.40000000000000002])
```